# Joining files in Coffescript

Tags: coffeescript

I am currently looking to use RequireJS to ensure modularity in the front end side of my project written in Coffeescript. Is there a way to use "import" directives in coffeescript so that you could recursive compile a large number of ".coffee" files into a single ".js" file - and potentially minify it too. I know there is a "join" argument you can pass to the coffeescript compiler, but it would be really useful to just reference files from one to another.

Secondly, it should be able to do this compilation really fast, so that the filewatcher can immediately change the entire output .js file every time any file (out of hundreds of files) was changed.

In addition, if it provided inbuilt minification/obfuscation that would be GREAT!

Comment: Use [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to [compile the .coffee files](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee) and [concat the files](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat). You could use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) as well to modularize your scripts.

Comment: I don't think Coffeescript can do this. However, there are tools that add this kind of functionality, e.g. https://github.com/fairfieldt/coffeescript-concat