# How to concatenate compiled coffeescript files?

Tags: compilation, coffeescript

With Coffeescript `coffee` command, it is possible to compile a coffee source file into its JavaScript equivalent with `-c` flag:

```
coffee -c toto.coffee
```

Shall produce an appropriate `toto.js` file.

Now what I would like to do is to compile many `.coffee` files into their respective `.js` equivalents and then concatenate them into a final library file. Something like this:

```
coffee -c toto.coffee
coffee -c foo.coffee
coffee -c bar.coffee
??? toto.js foo.js bar.js # Would produce a final .js file
```

The coffeescript command proposed me to do the following:

```
cat toto.coffee foo.coffee bar.coffee | coffee -c -s > library.js
```

But the problem is, if I modify one line in one coffee file, the entire library would have to be recompiled.

Neither the `coffee` command nor one of [coffeescript build tools](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/Build-tools) solved my problem.

I also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867606/joining-files-in-coffescript), where **gruntjs** is mentioned, but I didn't find any clear explanations on how I should use it in my specific case.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the coffeescript compiler watching for changes using -w flag. So everytime you change a line only this file will be recompiled just after save.

The concat can also automatically concatenate all files together after at least one changed. But as far as I know you have to code a nodejs helper therefor. I would use the [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) library to do so.

Comment: I have the last version of the coffeescript compiler, but it seems that whatever I do with, the `-w` flag does not change anything to its behavior. And anyway, it does not really answer my question since I didn't ask for a way to recompile a file when it changes (I can do it with a Makefile) but to concatenate compiled coffeescript files into one.